# Find pattern and replace Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a file test.xml
This contain content like bellow

```
<logger name="audit-log" level="${AUDIT_LEVEL:-OFF}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="AUDIT-LOG-ASYNC"/>
```

I wanna use ansible to replace level="${AUDIT_LEVEL:-OFF}" ==> level="something".
My ansible code like this but it doesn't work.

```
    tasks:
      - name: Ansible replace string example
        replace:
          path: test.xml
          regexp: '"${AUDIT_LEVEL:-OFF}"'
          replace: '"something"'
```

Please help me.
Thank.

Comment: You can consider using [xml module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/xml_module.html) which can work with XML files better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)

for example :

```
 - name: set APP_URL
   lineinfile: dest=/file_path regexp='level="${AUDIT_LEVEL:-OFF}"' line=level=something
```

I suggest defining the values to be changed first as a variable and then using it in the `lineinfile` field.